# Python script to launch and configure several programms

Tags: java, python, scripting, subprocess, python-requests

I've got an application which I want to debug locally. To do so, I have to run `Consul` first (it's a `jar`), then I have to call 2 two `REST API` methods so I call two `POST`s. Then I launch `elasticmq-server` and call `8` `GET`s.

At the moment I have launching `jar`s in a `bat` file, but it makes it useless for `UNIX`. I tried the following:

`subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'elasticmq-server-0.8.12.jar'], shell=True)`

but it doesn't work as I want. I expect `jar`s to launch in separate consoles after double-clicking on script.py. Is it possible? Below I attach the `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example`:

**My code**

```
import subprocess
import time, sys
import requests


subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'elasticmq-server-0.8.12.jar'], shell=True)
#call("my.bat") - it works on Windows, but not on Linux
time.sleep(5) #elastic must complete launch - it usually takes 1024 milsec, so I w8 5 just in case.
requests.get('http://localhost:8888/?Action=CreateQueue&QueueName=top-secret')
requests.get('http://localhost:8888/?Action=CreateQueue&QueueName=top-secret2')
requests.get('http://localhost:8888/?Action=CreateQueue&QueueName=top-secret3')
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:7777/some/catalogs/register', data = {"JSON WITH DATA FOR CONSUL")
```

**Expected behavior**

1. Launch script with a double click.
2. Launch consul in new console,
3. Launch elastic in new console,
4. Wait 2-5 seconds - it already works.
5. Call requests - it already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for a fact, that you cannot port the said `call` method between Windows and Linux. You have to search for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `subprocess` module has specific support for handling new window creation on Windows with [startupinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO).
On *nix and Linux you want to actually spawn a new terminal emulator so you would call something like:
`x-terminal-emulator -e 'bash -c "sleep 20"'` .... but this likely would not work on Mac...
And you need to effectively test which OS you are on.